# How do i authenticate a rest call in firebase?

Tags: rest, firebase, restful-authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to do a rest call on some data protected by some rule using the aid of my user, so i need to had the token to my request. 
depending of which version of firebase documentation there is different way:
old and deprecated way (https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/):

```
'https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/users/jack/name.json?auth=<TOKEN>'
```

new way and i m quoting the doc (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth#section-get):

> Using the access token
>   The Database REST API will accept access_token= on the query string or header Authenticate: Bearer  to authenticate a request with a service account.

```
'https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/users/jack/name.json?access_token=<TOKEN>'
```

the new way is not working for me even if I used the new firebase console when i set it up, and even if the token that i m using is generated using the new Firebase sdk. Does someone know why only the deprecated way is working? I was interested to put the token in the header of my requests but can not do.

Comment: if my response below is not working can you provide the error message you get please ?

Comment: Does anyone have this working? I've used the github  example [link](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/exampletokengenerator) to generate a token and sign in with it from the custom sign in page. The example works fine. However, when I use the generated access token (i.e. the "accessToken" results from customauth.html) via curl or postman (i.e. Authorization header - Bearer token) I get permission denied (403)

Comment: The error message is always the same:
403 (Forbidden)
{ "error": "Permission denied." }

Comment: access_token works for me.... Adding the header somehow is not working for me via Okhttp ..... works when i use a REST client though... can't figure out why yet

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the access_token in the headers.

> **Header name** : Authorization
>
> **Header content** : Bearer  *the_token*

To try it and put some headers you can use some tools like postman for google chrome or other tools.

Comment: As I said in my question, i tried what is written in the new firebase doc. So i tried what you just said and re-try using postman just to confirm it. It is not working for me. What works is what is written in the deprecated doc using: ?auth=<Token> set up in the url

Comment: are you able to put the token in the header to retrieve the protected data? is it working for you?

Comment: I'm on the new console and followed the directions from here: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth#section-get

Both with Postman and a browser I get Permission Denied.
Do we need to do anything in the Console. Enable Auth?

Comment: It is a bug / unimplemented functionality. Neither Authorization: Bearer <idToken> nor url?access_token=idToken works.

I think Firebase have silently dropped their REST API. Their JS Web API works correctly with Web Sockets, but the REST API has gone.

I am returning back to Kinvey.

Comment: I was told by their support staff that you use ?auth=<access-token> but I'm still working with them because it reports a permission denied (401 unauthorized) response still.

Comment: OK so I figured it out and I am successfully sending GET requests using access-key to my database. I wrote an answer for some more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520696/how-do-i-access-my-firebase-database-via-http-rest-api/40567107#40567107

Answer (score 2):

For java:
I tried to use *auth* to access DatabaseRealtime. 
Run:

```
curl 'https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com/users.json?auth=DATABASE_SECRET'
```

It worked but this way deprecated. 
After that I tried to use *access_token*
I met issue when use *access_token* to query Database in my firebase project.
I already found out root cause for bugs I met before. **Because access_token is generated incorrectly.** I tried to generate access_token again, tried to use the access_token as bellow:

**1. add google-api-client into *pom.xml***

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**2. Get token**

> ```
>  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>            GoogleCredential googleCred = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new 
>            FileInputStream("C://realtime.json"));
>            GoogleCredential scoped = googleCred.createScoped(
>                          Arrays.asList(
>        // or use firebase.database.readonly for read-only access
>            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database",                           
>     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
>                           )
>                   );
>                   scoped.refreshToken();
>                   String token = scoped.getAccessToken();
>                   System.out.println(token);
>               }
> ```

**3. try to access database**
Copy the value printed out above 
Run curl:

> ```
> curl 'https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com/users.json?access_token=TOKEN'
> ```

It worked well.

For more information refer link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth#section-get

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
 try (InputStream is = new ClassPathResource("your-admin-info.json").getInputStream()) {

      GoogleCredential googleCred = GoogleCredential.fromStream(is);
      scoped = googleCred.createScoped(
          Arrays.asList(
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database",
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
          )
      );
      scoped.refreshToken();
      scoped.getAccessToken();
```

your-admin-info.json is the Service Admin account info that you can generate on your accounts

Comment: What if I'm not using Java? I just want to send data from my server to firebase.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Only adding the token in the Authorization header did not work but the old way of including 'auth=' in the request worked. I think that might be a bug in Firebase.

My solution is to use both the new way and the old way, i.e. including 'auth=' in the request and also the token in the Authorization header. So after they fix the problem your app will continue to work.

Btw those answers about rules are incorrect, if the problem is caused by rules the error will be 401 unauthorized instead of 403 with message 'permission denied '

Comment: Ok I edited the answer to be more obvious and I hope you find it easier to understand now

Answer (score -2):

You need to check if the rules are configured correctly.

There are 4 options to use to Authenticate.

[image: 4 options to use to Authenticate in firebase]

> Rules will need to be configured differently for each Options.

Try the rule below:

[image: Firebase Rule]

Comment: the problem is not about the rule but about how to authenticate. I m able to authenticate when i follow what is explained in the deprecated doc, but not what is explained in the new version, like explained in my question