# Converting Firebase app code to use Fetch API

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fetch-api

I'm working through the code in this repository [React-powered Hacker News client](https://insin.github.io/react-hn) and would like to modify this to use `fetch` instead of the Hacker News [firebase](https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/) API specific code that is currently used (as a learning exercise).

[This](https://github.com/insin/react-hn/blob/classic/src/services/HNService.js) is the code requiring the `firebase/app` and `firebase/database`.  Before I spend a lot of time on this is it feasible for me (with only basic Javascript/React experience) to update this to use `fetch` instead of firebase proprietary code?

My understanding is that I could use fetch to retrieve the data i.e. something based on:

```
fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Work with JSON data here
    console.log(data)
  })

  })
```

I'm not sure how I would emulate these kind of functions though as they as using `firebase.database()` code.

```
function storiesRef(path) {
  return api.child(path)
}

function itemRef(id) {
  return api.child('item/' + id)
}

function userRef(id) {
  return api.child('user/' + id)
}

function updatesRef() {
  return api.child('updates/items')
```

Comment: Assuming your data structure is the same, you should be able to access the data object in the same way; so for your `itemRef` function: `return data.item[id];`
As long as you have data returned from your api request from the given endpoint you should be able to reason about it like any typical object.

Comment: By the way, if you want to query a Firebase DB url, you should append `.json` to the end of the url (see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data).
Although the REST API requires token authentication (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520696/how-do-i-access-my-firebase-database-via-http-rest-api) and is intended to be used directly from the command line or server (at least for full CRUD operations).

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Could you put the suggested code in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data structure is the same, you should be able to access the data object in the same way; so for your `itemRef` function: `return data.item[id];`

```
function userRef(id) {
   return dataAPI.user[id];
}

var user = userRef('1234567890xxxx');
```

As long as you have data returned from your api request from the given endpoint you should be able to reason about it like any typical object.

```
var dataAPI = fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0.json') // append .json at the end of the url to make a RESTful request
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Work with JSON data here
    return data;
  }, error => {
    console.error('onRejected function called: ' + error.message);
  })


function storiesRef(path) {
  //return api.child(path)
  return dataAPI[path];
}

function itemRef(id) {
  //return api.child('item/' + id)
  return dataAPI.item[id];
}

function userRef(id) {
  //return api.child('user/' + id)
  return dataAPI.user[id];
}

function updatesRef() {
  //return api.child('updates/items')
  return dataAPI.updates.items;
}
```

**Some other notes:**

1. to query a Firebase DB url, append `.json` to the end of the url
   (see: [firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start](http://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) and
   [firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data](http://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data)).
2. the Firebase REST API requires token authentication (see:
       [stackoverflow.com/questions/40520696/how-do-i-access-my-firebase-database-via-http-rest-api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520696/how-do-i-access-my-firebase-database-via-http-rest-api)).
3. the Firebase REST API is intended to be used directly from the
   command line or server (at least for full CRUD operations).

Comment: I get `{
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}` for https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0.json`. The request would need to be something like `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8863.json` The current code uses the firebase api and I would like use fetch if possible but it appears to be a non trivial task to make this work.  Thanks.